# $w=\sqrt{z^2-1}$ as a conformal mapping

Tags: complex-analysis

I am currently studying complex analysis (finally!). My lecturer said, that in order to have $w=\sqrt{z^2-1}$ as a well-defined function, as well as a conformal mapping, the domain should be:
$$\mathbb{C}\setminus\left\{z\mid \left|\Re\{z\}\right|<1, \Im\{z\}=0\right\}$$

In other words, the domain should be every $z$ but the real values between $-1$ and $1$. I don't understand why - why would $\frac 12$ be problematic, meaning $w$ would be multivalued there, but $-\frac 32$ or $i$ wouldn't be problematic. I admire my lecturer but he didn't seem to explain that specific idea very well.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Your lecturer is making a choice of a branch cut. What you choose it to be is somewhat irrelevant; in this case, just note $w = \exp(\tfrac{1}{2} \log(z^2 - 1))$ and choose the standard branch cut on the negative axis for $\log(z)$. We have $z^2 - 1 < 0$ exactly on the unit disk, and the restriction to the negative axis is $[-1,1]$. This is what your lecturer meant.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen I understood your explanation (thank you for that), but I now realize that my problem might be a little more basic. Why is the branch cut (for the logarithm) even needed? I know it is necessary so that the logarithm won't be multivalued, but I can't understand why this is the result. In other words, why a domain *without* a branch cut would make the logarithm multivalued?

Comment: A good and worthy question that I'm positive has been answered here plenty of times. Search for an existing post asking this question, and if you can't find anything create a new question focused on that. I imagine you'll get a good answer or your question will be marked as a duplicate to a good answer; if you still have questions ping me in a comment and I'll answer as I find time.

Comment: Here's a little search tip: https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csqrt%7Bz%5E2-1%7D%24%2C%20branch%2C%20cut&p=1